Nothing is happening when I'm running my python file, tkinter
I'm fairly new to programming, python and Tkinter and I've been working on a project now for a while in VSC, but suddenly it stopped working and I don't understand why. I didn't really do anything and when I try to run the python file everything just freezes, I can't click run other projects either unless I close and reopen Visual Studio Code. I can run other projects but not my big one. I thought it was because the program was too big for my computer but it doesn't work on my stationary either so I'm really confused now. Does someone now how to fix this? It doesn't show any error btw, it just freezes.
I've tried closing the app and restarting the computer and also debugging the program since I thought that would fix it but it didn't.
import customtkinter as ctk
from Settings import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, font
import tkinter.messagebox as tkmb
class App(ctk.CTk):
def __init__(self, size):
    super().__init__()
    self.geometry(f"{size[0]}x{size[1]}")
    self.title("Ordkoll")
    self.bind("<Escape>", lambda event: self.quit())
    #self.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
    self.menu = Meny(self)
    #self.login = LoggaIn(self)
    self.mainloop()
    

class LoggaInSideBar (ctk.CTkFrame):
def __init__(self, parent, start_pos, end_pos):
    super().__init__(master = parent, fg_color= "white")
    
    #General attributes
    self.start_pos = start_pos + 0.03
    self.end_pos = end_pos - 0.02
    self.width = abs(start_pos - end_pos)
    self._corner_radius = 20
    
    
    # Animation logic
    self.pos = self.start_pos
    self.in_start_pos = True


    self.place(relx = self.start_pos, rely=0.05, relwidth = self.width, relheight = 0.9)
    


def animate (self):
    
    if self.in_start_pos:
        self.animate_forward()
    else: 
        self.animate_backwards()

def animate_forward(self):
    if self.pos > self.end_pos:
        self.pos -= 0.005
        self.place(relx = self.pos, rely=0.05, relwidth = self.width, relheight = 0.9)
        self.after(5, self.animate_forward)
    else:
        self.in_start_pos = False

def animate_backwards(self):
    if self.pos < self.start_pos:
        self.pos += 0.005
        self.place(relx = self.pos, rely=0.05, relwidth = self.width, relheight = 0.9)
        self.after(5, self.animate_backwards)
    else:
        self.in_start_pos = True

class Meny(ctk.CTkFrame):
def __init__(self, parent):
    global font
    font = ctk.CTkFont(family = FONT1, size = MAIN_TEXT_SIZE, weight="bold")
    super().__init__(parent, fg_color= "grey15")
    self.logga_in_sidebar = LoggaInSideBar(self, 1, 0.76)
    self.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
    self.skapa_widgets_meny()

  
    

def skapa_widgets_meny(self):
    global loggainframe
    
    välkommen = ctk.CTkLabel(self, text="Välkommen till Ordkollen!", fg_color="grey15", text_color="white")
    #spela_knapp = ctk.CTkButton(self, text="Spela Som Gäst", bg_color= "grey15", text_color= "grey15",command=self.visa_spel)
    loggain_knapp = ctk.CTkButton(self, text = "Logga in", bg_color= "grey15", text_color= "grey15", command = self.logga_in_sidebar.animate)

    loggainframe= ctk.CTkFrame(self.logga_in_sidebar)
    
    

    #spela_knapp.place(rely=0.4, relx=0.5, anchor="center", relheight=0.1, relwidth=0.2)
    välkommen.place(rely=0.1, relx=0.5, anchor="center")
    loggainframe.place(rely = 0.3,relx = 0.5, relwidth = 0.8, relheight = 0.5, anchor = "center")
    loggain_knapp.place(rely= 0.6, relx = 0.5, anchor = "center")
   

    

    
    self.columnconfigure((0, 1, 2, 3), weight=1, uniform="a")
    self.rowconfigure((0, 1, 2, 3), weight=1, uniform="a")
    self.loggainframe = LoggaIn(loggainframe)
    
    

class LoggaIn(ctk.CTkFrame):
def init(self, parent):
super().init(parent)
    global username
    global password
    global user_pass
    global new_window
    global user_entry

    username = "Geeks"
    password = "12345"
    
    
    self.place(rely=0, relx = 0)
    self.loginwidgets()



def login(self):
    super().__init__(self)
    
    
    if user_entry.get() == username and user_pass.get() == password: 
        tkmb.showinfo(title="Login Successful",message="You have logged in Successfully") 
        ctk.CTkLabel(new_window,text="GeeksforGeeks is best for learning ANYTHING !!").pack() 
    elif user_entry.get() == username and user_pass.get() != password: 
        tkmb.showwarning(title='Wrong password',message='Please check your password') 
    elif user_entry.get() != username and user_pass.get() == password: 
        tkmb.showwarning(title='Wrong username',message='Please check your username') 
    else: 
        tkmb.showerror(title="Login Failed",message="Invalid Username and password") 

    

def loginwidgets(self):
    #super().__init__(self)
    #titelloggain = ctk.CTkLabel(self,text="This is the main UI page") 

    #titelloggain.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.1, anchor = "center") 
    
    
    frame2 = ctk.CTkFrame(self) 

    self.rowconfigure((0))
    self.columnconfigure((0))


    frame2.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nswe") 

    frame2.rowconfigure((0,1,2,3,4), weight=1, uniform = "a")
    frame2.columnconfigure((0))


    label2 = ctk.CTkLabel(master=frame2,text='Modern Login System UI') 
    label2.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nswe") 


    user_entry= ctk.CTkEntry(master=frame2,placeholder_text="Username") 
    user_entry.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = "nswe")

    user_pass= ctk.CTkEntry(master=frame2,placeholder_text="Password",show="*") 
    user_pass.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = "nswe") 


    button = ctk.CTkButton(master=frame2,text='Login',command=LoggaIn.login(self))
    button.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = "nswe") 

    checkbox = ctk.CTkCheckBox(master=frame2,text='Remember Me') 
    checkbox.grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = "nswe") 

   
    
   



    

 







    

app = App((500, 300))
I'm sorry I'm a little slow but I don't think there's any loops, and I can't debug it. Here's the code, I've no idea if it will help or how I should share it.
Another edit. I'll try to explain exactly what is happening. So if I start VSC everything works fine, I can run other programs and so on. But as soon as I try to run this program everything just stops working. I can move my mouse around but I can't run any other programs and no error messages shows.

Sounds like your code might have an infinite loop in it somewhere.  But you didn't share the code, so it's hard to say for sure exactly what the problem is.

Use the debugger or add some print calls to find out what is executed and where it stops.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

super().__init__(self) should be removed inside LoggaIn.login().  Also inside LoggaIn.loginwidgets(), command=LoggaIn.login(self) should be command=self.login instead.  There is other error after fixing those issues.
